# VLC player installation error - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty2) but 2.2.1~trusty2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.16) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
     Depends: libegl1-x11 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgles1 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libgles2 but it is a virtual package
     Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:1.0) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the mentioned libraries and packages already installed for the installation of vlc. You should have an active internet connection to do the following.

Try installing it from the terminal as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

still if you get dependency errors that may be because you need to update your repositories' package lists.

type the following to update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then try the first command.

If you want complete offline installation, you can use **Synaptics Package Manager** for that. But then also you should download the dependencies from one system with internet and then install it offline in yours. There are many posts explaining the offline installation of softwares.